# How to get rid of the blue selection border around SwiftUI TextFields?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have created two textfields with the following code:

```
VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
    TextField("World Name", text: self.$WorldName)
        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/28))
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.75)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color.init(white: 0.28))
    )
    TextField("World Seed", text: self.$WorldSeed)
        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/28))
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.75)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color.init(white: 0.28))
    )
    Button (action: {
        withAnimation {
            self.back.toggle()
        }
        // Is there a way to "deselect" any textfields here
    }){
        Text("Back")
    }
}
```

Why is it when I click on one, there is a blue border that does not fade out with the animation, and how can I remove it? This question is specific, and I have provided code, and necessary details, I don't see why it should be too hard to answer.

So in summarized terms, I need to know:

- How to get rid of this blue selection border

Or

- How to immediately deselect the text field within the button's action,
- Get the border to properly line up with the TextField if I apply a padding or round corners.

The only blue in this picture is the border I am referring to
[image: The only blue in this picture is the border I am referring to]

As shown in this screenshot, the textfield is round, but the selection border does not get round corners to reflect the rounded rectangle shape of the entry
[image: As shown in this screenshot, the textfield is round, but the selection border does not get round corners to reflect the rounded rectangle shape of the entry]

The blue border does not fit the padding

[image: The blue border does not fit the padding]

I added a padding like this `.padding([.leading, .trailing], 6)`

Comment: can you provide screenshot

Comment: which blue there is no blue border while selection on textfield, because it has a `PlainTextFieldStyle` style

Comment: @Salman500 Added screenshots. Shown the border

Comment: @Salman500 blue border shows up when using PlainTextFieldSyle on macos

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the blue border (which appears on macos even when using `PlainTextFieldStyle`) by extending NSTextField like so:

```
extension NSTextField {
        open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
                get { .none }
                set { }
        }
}
```

See Apple Developer Forum answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124617)

Comment: Nice. This also works with many other NS view subclasses like NSTabView, NSButton etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which blue border are you referring to, if you are referring to blue border for `textfield`, there is no blue border beacuse you have given a [PlainTextFieldStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/plaintextfieldstyle)

To deselect the textfield

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first?.endEditing(true)
```

To have a rounded `textfield` with padding

```
ZStack {
    Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.clear)
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(Color("appcolor").opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 1))

    TextField("Enter some text", text: $worldName)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 6)
}.frame(height: 42)
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it, however I think any confusion is due to the fact that I am coding for macos. When you click on a text field, it becomes "selected" and a blue border appears around it.

Comment: However, perhaps code for iOS will also work for macOS so I will still look into your answer

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @ZeeshanSuleman I found a solution to remove the blue border on macOS, see my answer to the question